# Is there anything I can do for PowerQuery to actually refresh in Excel for the Web?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I created a Web.Contents query calling a public REST API that refreshes perfectly in Excel Desktop. The API token is in the URL so access works through an anonymous connection.

The same query returns an error message in Excel Online:

> "We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this
> workbook."

I tried several times over several days to rule out transient issues.

The [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-US/client/results?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=XLWAEndUser&version=15&omkt=en-US&ver=15&apps=WDWAENDUSER%2CXLWAENDUSER%2CPPWAENDUSER%2CONWAENDUSER&HelpID=ExcelRefreshFailed) linked from the error modal box states that:

> "Depending on how your particular environment is configured, you might
> or might not be able to refresh the data in a workbook that you are
> viewing in a browser window. For example, the ability to refresh
> external data depends, in large part, on how Excel Servicesis
> configured. For more information, contact a SharePoint administrator."

This is very unhelpful (where is said SharePoint administrator supposed to go for help?) and sounds like it was written for earlier, on-premises version of the SharePoint/Excel stack. I looked in my O365 and SharePoint admin settings and didn't see anything relevant to this issue.

Is refreshing Web.Contents queries simply not supported yet in Excel Online?

My end goal is to schedule automated refreshes by running an Office script via Power Automate. I already set that up but that's obviously a moot point if the refresh action itself is broken. I'm trying to get rid of desktop automation for this particular scenario to have a cloud-based automated refresh solution just like we've been able to do with Power BI for years.

Comment: AFAIK it’s not possible yet

Comment: Looks that way. I get that it's a preview but this is still very poorly implemented and documented by Microsoft. I was pointed to this thread where Guy Hunkin from Microsoft said on Dec 1st 2020 that it was not possible at the time: 
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/data-connection-refresh-error/m-p/1398375